# a question on race, time, distance

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, logic

P and Q are two points on a 1km long circular track. The distance PQ along the track is 200m. Rohan started running from P and sohan started simultaneously from Q in same direction.Both reached P simultaneously.If both simultaneously from P in opposite direction they meet for first time at 1000/9sec. Find time taken to meet for first time if they started from Q in same direction

A 2000
B 1000
C 500
D 2500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using the equation $\text{speed} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$ a lot of times, and assume that the runners never change their speed.  Let $s_R$ be the speed of Rohan and $s_S$ be the speed of Sohan.

"Rohan started running from P and sohan started simultaneously from Q in same direction.Both reached P simultaneously."

Their times are equal, $\text{time} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}$.

$$\frac{1000}{s_R} = \frac{1000 - 200}{s_S}\tag{1}$$

"If both simultaneously from P in opposite direction they meet for first time at 1000/9sec."  Let $d_R$ be the distance Rohan ran here, and $d_S$ be the distance Sohan ran here.

$$d_R + d_S  = 1000 \tag{2}$$
$$\frac{s_R}{d_R} = \frac{s_S}{d_S} = \frac{1000}{9} \tag{3}$$

"Find time taken to meet for first time if they started from Q in same direction."

(1) Tells us that Sohan is faster, he will lap Rohan.  So when they meet, Sohan will have traveled an extra 1000m.  Let $t$ be be the time in question, $x_S$ be the distance Sohan runs here and $x_R$ be the distance Rohan runs here.

$$x_S = x_R + 1000 \tag{4}$$
$$t = \frac{x_S}{s_S} = \frac{x_R}{s_R} \tag{5}$$

7 equations and a lot of variables.  You are trying to find $t$. (1), (2), and (3) are 4 linear equations and 4 variables.  If you use the values from that, then (4) and (5) becomes 3 linear equations and 3 more variables.